# Python - 'No module named..' using visual studio portable

Tags: python

I am using visual studio portable to create a TCP simulator - using a client.py, state.py and server.py 
when executing the code it is producing an error of: 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'State' - can anyone help?

this is the line where error exists 'from State import *'

and this is what the terminal produces:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Chloe/Documents/Computer Science Uni Work/Final Year/Computer Networks/Coursework 2/New/client.py", line 1, in 
    from State import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'State'

Below is what is included in state.py

```
    class State:
    state = None #abstract class
    CurrentContext = None
    def __init__(self, Context):
        self.CurrentContext.Context = Context

class StateContext:
    stateIndex = 0
    CurrentState = None
    availableStates = []

    def setState(self, newstate):
        self.CurrentState = self.availableStates[newstate]
        self.stateIndex = newstate

    def getStateIndex(self):
        return self.stateIndex
```

Many thanks

Comment: Could you post the code causing the problem? And also any related code

Comment: I've uploaded the line where error exists :)

Comment: What is the state module? We have no idea what's in state.py

Comment: You need to provide more information. there could be many reasons, including the absence of the `State` module obviously. It could be anything. for the start, check your path.

Comment: Please include the directory structure of your project. Do you have an `__init__.py` file anywhere?